# Main activity doesn't come back after pressing back button

Tags: java, android, back-button

Below is my code which I am using in my application:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main2);
            b3=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.p1);
            b3.fromAsset("1.pdf").load();
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main2);
            b4=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.p1);
            b4.fromAsset("2.pdf").load();
        }
    });
}
```

When I am trying to press back button my main activity doesn't come back. I am not sure why.

How to handle it?

Comment: If your intention is to flip between 2 UI's, I would recommend using Fragments and then using fragment.addToBackStack for your usecase.

Comment: You need to override `onBackPress()` in your activity

Comment: just override onBackPress() method of your activity, and write the logic to close the current PDFView

Comment: what exactly does `doesn't come back` mean? What you expect it to do, and what it does instead?

Answer (score 1):

You must `@Override` `onBackPressed()` in your activity. Or if you `finish()`'d your `MainActivity` while calling this one (assuming you're calling it from the `MainActivity`) you can just "not finish" it and the back button will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code for your `Activity`. It is not required to override the `onBackPressed` function as this is a default behaviour. However, you can use only one layout at a time in your activity which you have mentioned in the `setContentView`.

So get the pdf viewer layouts in your `activity_main` and then load the pdf there like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.p1);
    b4=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.p1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b3.fromAsset("1.pdf").load();
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b4.fromAsset("2.pdf").load();
        }
    });
}
```